# exit code 127 Email notification

Tags: svn, post-commit

Good Morning Everyone,

We are working on sending email notifications of SVN commits and we are following the steps oulined here: http://sandilands.info/sgordon/email-notifications-of-svn-commits

When testing, we still get following errors:

```
Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 127) with output:--
```

CP, CHOWN, CHMOD work smoothly.
Any help?

Comment: What does the post-commit hook do? Did you copy-n-paste their example directly? Show us some code :)

Comment: Also - are you saying that cp, chown, and chmod work smoothly within the hook, or running them on the command line?

Comment: A quick google says that `exit 127` is `command does not exist`... so what command is post-commit executing, that it can't find? Does `mailer.py` exist in the repo's `hooks` directory? Does `/usr/share/subversion/hook-scripts/commit-email.pl` exist?